# Android Studio IDE - No elements appears in Design Editor

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been using Android Studio since I started programming in Android, because I think that is 1 of the best IDEs for Android.

But, now when I want to put elements to my UI usign Design editor (Design using gui (not text)), the elements don't appear.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it constraintLayout?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: is not with an specific layout. It pass to me with constraintLayout and with relativeLayout.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Only not appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Following thing maybe help you

1. RefreshLayout

   - Go in Design part, from the design part select Design Surface icon (Three Layer icon) and click on Force refresh layout.
2. Invalidate caches and Restart

   - From the file menu select  "Invalidate caches and Restart".
3. Try with Theam change

   - From the design section please try the layout with different themes.
4. Update your build version.

All the above solution is temporary may be you doing something wrong in your design or not building proper so please do it

Comment: Not doing bad, because I asked other people and they do it like me but for them, It was ok. Thanks.

Comment: I will try to do what you said me.

Comment: Okay no problem once fixed please inform.

Comment: Ok. When fixed, I inform.

Comment: For me your answer,  has been my solution! All the 4 steps were fine for me! However, I have to say that other users than answered my post, they have in majority one of the steps your mentioned! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try **invalidated Cache/Restart** From File **->** Select Invalided Cache/Restart  **->**  Select Invalidate and Restart.

It's work for me.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried, I would say if it was ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Choose another theme (other than Holo, for example Theme)

This is a common problem . It can be easily solved by changing res/values/styles.xml to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do later.